# In Vim + Eclim, How to open "SearchContext" in vertical window

Tags: php, autocomplete, vim, eclim

I'm using Eclim, in doc [Suggested Vim Mappings](http://eclim.org/vim/mappings.html) , I know a mapping for PHP

```
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <cr> :PhpSearchContext<cr>
```

but it opens a horizontal window, how to change it to a vertical window?

Just like diff between `:help` and `:vert bo help`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place in your `.vimrc` the following:

```
let g:EclimDefaultFileOpenAction = 'vsplit'
```

Or, you can add such settings for PHP only:

```
let g:EclimPhpSearchSingleResult = 'vsplit'
```

Unfortunately, such value '`vsplit`' [is not stated](http://goo.gl/us97V) in the Eclim's documentation, I just remember the same question in the eclim-user mailing list.